# Why is a fixed $j$ eigenspace irreducible?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory

In his development of angular momentum, Ballentine writes:

> The $(2j + 1)$-dimensional space spanned by the set of vectors $\{|j, m\rangle\}$, for fixed $j$ and all $m$ in the range $(−j \leq m \leq j)$, is an invariant irreducible subspace under rotations. To say that the subspace is invariant means that a vector within it remains within it after rotation. This is so because no other values of $j$ are introduced into the linear combination of (7.71). To say that the subspace is irreducible means that it contains no smaller invariant subspaces. Proof of irreducibility is left as an exercise for the reader.

I am confused about how to supply said proof. The invariance follows because any rotation operator commutes with $J^2$, and so rotations do not map the $|j,m \rangle$ out of the fixed $j$ eigenspace. I am struggling to prove irreducibility. Obviously, the structure of the proof should be something like "Take any subspace spanned by some strict subset of the $|j,m \rangle$. Then observe that there is a rotation operator which maps an element of that subspace outside of the subspace". Can anyone supply a hint (or just the quick proof) as to how I should pick said rotation operator?

Comment: Simpler to do using ladder operators $J_\pm$.  Start with any $\vert jm\rangle$ and repeated use of $J_\pm$ gives you all the vectors of fixed $j$ and none others.

Comment: Why is that equivalent? Definitionally I am trying to show irreducibility under the action of the rotation operators. @ZeroTheHero

Comment: If the space is irreducible under the action of the algebra, it must be so under the group since the group just exponentiates the algebra.  (I’m not super careful with words but certainly right for angular momentum).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Yes, what you assert  is true for compact (connected) Lie groups. Problems with domains arise in the non compact case, but it is substantially true also in general…

Comment: @ValterMoretti this is precisely why the non-compact case is *soooo* much richer and interesting.

Comment: Reading the title (v1), a fixed $j$ eigenspace does not have to be irreducible: it could in principle contain several copies of $(2j\!+\!1)$-dimensional irreps.

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes you are right and I was about remarking the same objection yesterday. However, in the text ,states are labeled as $|j, m\rangle$ and there is no room here for further degeneracy.

Comment: @Valter Moretti. I agree.

Comment: @Qmechanic You are correct although this type of question usually assumes no degeneracy.  In this case of course you find all states killed by $J_+$, organize an orthonormal basis in that subspace, and use $J_-$ to define the states with $m<j$ in each subspaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take your rotation $R(\Omega)$ and write it in factorized form
$$
R(\Omega)=e^{\xi J_+}e^{\eta J_z}e^{\zeta J_-}
$$
It is always possible to do this and in fact the parameters $\xi,\eta$ and $\zeta$ can be found using any faithful irrep.  (People usually use the $2\times 2$ 'cuz it's the simplest for this purpose.)

Here, $J_\pm$ and $J_z$ would be the $(2j+1)\times (2j+1)$ matrix representations of the appropriate operators.

Then, expand $e^{\zeta J_-}=1+\zeta J_- +\frac12 \zeta^2 J_-^2+\ldots$
to show that, starting from $\vert jm\rangle$, you will reach every $\vert jm'\rangle$ with $m'\le m$, and in particular $\vert j,-j\rangle$.

$J_z$ does not change $m'$ so $e^{\eta J_z}$ will not generate any new states.  Finally, expand $e^{\xi J_+}$ acting on
$$e^{\eta J_z}e^{\zeta J_-}\vert jm\rangle\, . \tag{1}
$$  Then certainly you will eventually generate all the states $\vert jm''\rangle$ with $m''>m$ if only because, after enough applications, $e^{\xi J_+}\vert j,-j\rangle$ will produce something proportional to $\vert jm''\rangle$ with $m''>m$, and you know Eq.(1) must contain $\vert j,-j\rangle$.

Comment: Some of the details are lost on me here, but I think I get the broad strokes. At any rate, is there no easier (perhaps this is easy for you, thought the very first factorization is not something I've seen) proof that Ballentine maybe had in mind here?

Comment: I've accepted, but if anything easier comes to mind please let me know!

Comment: it’s the standard way of proving this, albeit I took the proof for the algebra and “exponentiated” it to a proof for group.  The factorization into an upper triangular subgroup, a diagonal matrix and a lower triangular subgroup is standard.